# Comparing two tab-separated files

Tags: python, perl, bash, bioinformatics

This is bioinformatics related question, but still a very much programming question. I failed to build up a few liners in bash for the problem given below and thought of asking it here. Kindly help.

Problem: I have two files (tab separated). File A looks like

```
chr1    17050255    234916798
chr1    36688211    36840408
chr1    153961765   154156955
chr1    154128722   154194653
chr1    154130378   154156872
chr1    207493679   207819735
```

This is a list of genomic coordinates.

File B also contains genomic coordinates in its first 3 columns and in fourth column it has a name.

```
chr1    1709155 1709324 MMM3
chr1    1709155 1709324 Sk-20
chr1    1709608 1709727 ZdaA
chr1    1709608 1709727 ZdaA
chr1    1709608 1709727 ZA
chr1    1709629 1709727 E-1
chr1    1709629 1709727 E-1
chr1    1709629 1709727 E-1
```

What I want to have the regions of file B (along with fourth column) which overlap with file A and print it like this

```
ChrA   StrtA    stpA    ChrB  SrtB  StpB       Name
```

Regions in file A come first then the regions with which it overlaps in file B along with the value of the fourth column in file B.

Thank you

Comment: How do you define "overlap"? Given the data above, what's your expected output?

Comment: An actual example of expected output that results from the example input is usually necessary for this type of question.  The strings of the "result" do not appear in the input, so the output does not demonstrate what you want in a clear way.

Comment: If you go the Python route, parsing the input files with the [csv](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) module will probably make your life easier.

Comment: You're bash script failed. Do you have anything in Perl or Python, or nothing it all? Showing any code may help understanding what you're trying to do and pointing you towards working code.

Comment: @steve: These are base pairs, so in chromosome 1, I have a fragment starting from 17050255 and ending at 234916798. If in file B also has a fragment which is in chromosome 1 and its starting or ending value lie within 17050255 and 234916798, it is defined as overlap.

Comment: @Evert: I am learning programming and I know bits and pieces of perl and python. Bash I know for sure. So please help me, I am just a beginner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **bedtools** intersectBed: http://code.google.com/p/bedtools/wiki/Usage#intersectBed

(you could also ask http://www.biostars.org/ )

Comment: I don't understand your problem: look at the options of intersectBed like -wa, use cut to reduce the numer of columns.

Comment: my comment came, too late ! :-)

Comment: I have solved it Pierre, I get the desired output with -wa & -wb option both together. thank you for enlightening me :)

Answer (score 2):

I definitely recommend looking at [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) to do something like this. Load both into separate DataFrames and then you should be able to merge them together in the format you are looking to see.

Comment: Are pandas going to look up overlaps? I think you would need to have exact matches, the overlap here does not mean equality in this case I believe.

Comment: @petr: No you don't have to put the nucleotide content in it. It is purely mathematical.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [DBD::CSV](https://metacpan.org/module/DBD%3a%3aCSV) to handle your problem in a SQL-ish way:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use utf8;
use warnings 'all';

use Data::Printer;
use DBI;

my $dbh = DBI->connect('dbi:CSV:', undef, undef, {
    f_encoding      => 'utf8',
    csv_quote_char  => undef,
    csv_escape_char => undef,
    csv_sep_char    => "\t",
    csv_eol         => "\n",
    csv_quote_space => 0,
    csv_quote_null  => 0,
    csv_tables      => {
        fileA       => { file => 'fileA.tsv' },
        fileB       => { file => 'fileB.tsv' },
    },
    RaiseError      => 1,
    PrintError      => 1,
}) or die "DBI/DBD::CSV error: " . $DBI::errstr;

my $sth = $dbh->prepare(<<SQL_QUERY);
    SELECT *
    FROM fileA
    JOIN fileB ON
        (StrtA <= StpB) OR (StrtB <= StpA)
    WHERE Name IS NOT NULL
SQL_QUERY

$sth->execute;
while (my $row = $sth->fetchrow_arrayref) {
    p $row;
}
$sth->finish;
$dbh->disconnect;
```

(I'm not sure if I understood your overlap condition, though)